# error: conversion from ‘char’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ in C++

Tags: string, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    string str1 = str[0];        // statement1

    str1 = str[0];               // statement2
    cout << str1 << endl;
}
```

Statement1 shows an error while statement2 runs fine. Could anyone please explain why this happens?

Comment: `string str1 = str[0];` what do you think this line does?

Comment: `str[0]` is the char at index 0, at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/ you can see the constructors for std::string, none of the std::string constructors accepts a char as the first argument; constructor #5 accepts a pointer to char along with number of bytes though, you could use that, eg `string str1(&str[0],1);`

Answer (score 0):

Statement 1 is attempting to use a constructor of `std::string` to initialize `str1` (even though you are using an `=` it still calls a constructor), however there is no constructor that makes a `std::string` from a single character. Statement 2 on the other hand is calling `std::string::operator=()` of which a suitable overload for a single character exists.